# how can I use un-blocked Bcast in MPI?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I want to hide the communication latency in MPI_Bcast.

As I know, I can use MPI_Isend/Irecv to make it, but when I use Bcast how can I make it un-blocked?

Answer (score 3):

While it's not quite final, the MPI 3.0 specification includes an `MPI_Ibcast`, along with other nonblocking collectives.  Recent versions of both MPICH2 and OpenMPI include implementations of these collectives.  There is also libNBC, but it's more of a proof-of-concept implementation, and does not focus on performance.

Speaking of performance: it may require some tuning.  You might find that enabling the background progress thread helps or hinders performance.  You can try calling `MPI_Test` periodically to ensure progress instead.   This is just like non-blocking point-to-point, except there are more messages being sent in the background, and performance tuning can yield larger gains.  Finally, on some hardware it is possible to offload collective communication from the CPU and get better computation/communication overlap.